# Can't deploy Qt Quick app to Mac OSX

Tags: macos, qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm trying to deploy an application to Mac OSX, but it doesn't work.

After build my app it seems to be working fine, running inside Qt Creator, I used QML and C++ to build the app. I've used the command line:

```
macdeployqt MyApp.app -dmg
```

After that a `.dmg` file is generated but the app inside that doesn't work. It opens an empty window. Worse than that, after deployed app execution also my app in Qt Creator starts to show only an empty window showing the following output:

> qrc:/qml/main.qml:1:1: module "QtQuick" is not installed 
>   qrc:/qml/main.qml:4:1: module "QtQuick.Controls" is not installed 
>   qrc:/qml/main.qml:2:1: module "QtQuick.Dialogs" is not installed 
>   qrc:/qml/main.qml:1:1: module "QtQuick" is not installed 
>   qrc:/qml/main.qml:4:1: module "QtQuick.Controls" is not installed 
>   qrc:/qml/main.qml:2:1: module "QtQuick.Dialogs" is not installed 
>   qrc:/qml/main.qml:1:1: module "QtQuick" is not installed 
>   qrc:/qml/main.qml:4:1: module "QtQuick.Controls" is not installed 
>   qrc:/qml/main.qml:2:1: module "QtQuick.Dialogs" is not installed

`otool -L` shows me this:

> @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtQuick.framework/Versions/5/QtQuick
>   (compatibility version 5.2.0, current version 5.2.0)
>   @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtQml.framework/Versions/5/QtQml
>   (compatibility version 5.2.0, current version 5.2.0)
>   @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/5/QtNetwork
>   (compatibility version 5.2.0, current version 5.2.0)
>   @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore
>   (compatibility version 5.2.0, current version 5.2.0)
>   @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui
>   (compatibility version 5.2.0, current version 5.2.0)
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL
>   (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Versions/A/AGL (compatibility
>   version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0) /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
>   (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 60.0.0)
>   /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current
>   version 1197.1.1)

I've deleted all my old Qt libraries that I've in my system (or I suppose to, can't find Qt in anywhere else now, only the 5.2 installation).
Anyone has any idea about what's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with Qt 5.0.1 and Qt 5.1.0. To fix it I created my own version of macdeployqt. I think it'll work for Qt 5.2.0. Please check it: https://github.com/MaximAlien/macdeployqt.

Answer (score 14):

Since Qt 5.2 a new option has been added to `macdeployqt` that parses all your QML files to see the frameworks you need and copy them properly. This is how I launch macdeployqt for my app:

```
macdeployqt path/to/my.app -qmldir=./path/to/my/qml/root -dmg
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna have a look on it :)

Comment: It definitely WORKS! Thx

Comment: Also, if you **do not provide** the `qmldir`, it will also break your project from compiling from the Qt Creator itself. So do provide it every time.