# Qt 5.5 deploy on OSX fails with simple HelloWorld app

Tags: macos, qt, qml

I'm using OSX 10.11.3 and QT 5.5. I'm creating the default QtQuick Application which is just an empty window with a 'Hello world' text in it.

I then build and run the app in Qt Creator which is fine. I then use macdeployqt  to 'package' the app for OSX.

The utility does not give any error, it just exits but when you try to run the app, the window doesn't load and the app icon just sits in the dock, probably not able to find its qml file

Does anyone know what's broken in Qt 5.5 and OSX 10.11 ?

Comment: Did you try [these flags](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20903329/2538363)? Sounds like an issue related to missing frameworks.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Let me check when I get back to my computer

Comment: Thank you, that did solve the issue.

Comment: Ok, I'm glad it solved the issue. I've flagged the question as duplicate of the linked one since the problem seemed (and actually is) the same.

Comment: Make sure to pass `-qmldir=path/to/your/qml` to macdeployqt, to make it package the qml plugins etc. used by your application. Run it from a terminal (the executable inside the bundle, not via open) to get error messages.