# Run qt qml app on another pc

Tags: qt, qml

I wrote some app in Qt 5.7.1 with Qml Quick 2.6. 
It does not run on another pc where Qt does not install.
In logs I see this error:
"[WRN] QQmlComponent: Component is not ready".
In Windows's Task Manager I see app is running, but there is no window of app.
All qml files I put in resourse file.

```
new QQmlComponent(&(this->engine),
                                  QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/qml/design/qml/main.qml")));
```

Dirs with app looks:
[image]

When I start app on another PC, there are no any message with errors about depence of some dlls. Please help...

Comment: Don't you need to deploy the whole `qml` directory?

Comment: I need to run app, all qml files I storage in resourse file. But when I run app on another pc seems app cannot file qml files. When I run on my pc app's workink. I have no idea what's wrong...

Comment: I'm talking about Qt's `qml` directory. You seem to only have copied `QtQuick.2` from it...

Comment: Use `windeployqt` with the qml flag, much like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20903329/2538363). You need that to ensure that the deploy tool recognizes for you the required quick dll/qml files and import them.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the correct (and minimal) set of DLL binaries copied over to the target machine isn't the easiest thing.  But there's standard documentation for it and a helper tool called [windeployqt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html) that you should check out.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html

Comment: I've got the same...window od app does not show, in task manager i can see that process.

Comment: The deployment tool doesn't work for me either. Which is why I use static linking for the applications I distribute to others, it just saves a lot of headaches.

Comment: @ddriver newer versions seems to work fine, granted you use them like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20903329/2538363) also on Windows. 2 I've used both Mac and Win with no particular issues. But yeah, static linking it's the easiest (and smallest) solution for sure.

Comment: I just installed 5.8, so I will give it a go.

Comment: @ddriver If you have compiled with mingw you need to manually copy libgcc, pthread and stdc. Don't know why they are not copied. It's working for me like that since a year (actually 2 years on Mac).

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo `For Windows desktop applications, the required runtime files for the compiler are also copied to the deployable folder by default` also I have `QMAKE_LFLAGS += -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++` in my PRO, all necessary dlls are there, it simply doesn't work. After windeployqt it only complains about `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll` missing, after that is copied the app is simply `unable to start correctly`. Actually, after I run windeployqt on the exe, it doesn't even work from creator, now it fails to find qml modules, so it would seem it actually breaks things further...

Comment: My last deploy on Win was in December. Maybe I don't remember something well. If I'll get the chance, I'll check it tomorrow at work.

Comment: @ddriver FWIW I've deployed two of my apps with 5.8 and had no issue. My steps were: 1) calling `qtenv2.bat` from cmd to set the compiler in the PATH 2) calling `windeployqt` with the `qmldir` flag to the source 3) renaming root Qt dir for testing 4) using all the feature of the apps.  I think you can possibly be hitting some sort of bug which would be interesting to investigate. At least because it took me like 1 min to deploy each app like this.

Comment: Maybe my project is too complex for the tool to handle, it uses a lot of Qt modules and several 3rd party libs. The deployment tool has not worked for it since the days of 5.5. It actually works if I manually copy the needed files. No big deal anyway, as I use a static binary for distribution. Oddly enough, deployment to android is just fine, it manages to pull in all the necessary files even for a dynamic build.